# How to create a comment box with time and date stamp in Access using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Completely new to VBA and need help with detailed instructions (dummy version for me).

I have a table with various columns and the following columns, specifically:

ReviewerComments
NewComment

I created a form with both of these fields and need to create an Append Comment button that moves the text from NewComment field and appends it to ReviewerComment field and time/date stamps the comments as they are added.  I named this button cmdAppendComment.

I had seen someone else post something and I tried, but as I am completely new to this I know I messed it up.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is what the VBA code looks like right now:

```
Private Sub cmdAppendComment_Click()
If (IsNull(NewComment.Value)) Then
    MsgBox ("Please provide a comment before clicking" & _
        "on the Append Comment button.")
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If (IsNull(ReviewerComments.Value)) Then
    ReviewerComments.Value = NewComment.Value & " ~ " & _
           VBA.DateTime.Date & " ~ " & VBA.DateTime.Time
  Else
    ReviewerComments.Value = ReviewerComments.Value & _
           vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           NewComment.Value & " ~ " & _
           VBA.DateTime.Date & " ~ " & VBA.DateTime.Time
  End If

  NewComment.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: When testing the button, I type in text in comment box, save and then type in text in the new comment box and click on the button.  The error message is: Compile Error: Syntax Error.  It highlights lines 11-14 red and yellow highlight on the first line (with "Definition" stating: Identifier under cursor is not recognized".  My new comment is not appended and nothing happens.

Comment: That may be what my error is, what is that and how do I set it?

Comment: Sorry, as I said, VERY new to VBA.  What is "Definition" and how to I fix that if it is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some suggestions for your code:

**1.** Do not check if a textbox is null but how many characters your textbox has. You should always do it that way because otherwise you tend to get errors.

```
If (len(Me.NewComment.Value & "") > 0) Then
    MsgBox ("Please provide a comment before clicking" & _
        "on the Append Comment button.")
    Exit Sub
  End If
```

Here you check the length of the string in your textbox. You need to append "" because otherwise you tend to get null-errors or something similar.

**2.** You forgot to reference the objects in your form correctly. You have your form and in that form you put your textboxes and also your VBA-code. Your can reference all your objects with "Me.[FormObjects]".

The compiler complains that "NewComment.Value" or "ReviewerComment.Value" is not initialized or in other words not dimensioned. With correct reference this should stop.

```
Private Sub cmdAppendComment_Click()
If (len(Me.NewComment.Value & "") > 0) Then
    MsgBox ("Please provide a comment before clicking" & _
        "on the Append Comment button.")
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If (IsNull(Me.ReviewerComments.Value)) Then
    Me.ReviewerComments.Value = Me.NewComment.Value & " ~ " & _
           VBA.DateTime.Date & " ~ " & VBA.DateTime.Time
  Else
    Me.ReviewerComments.Value = Me.ReviewerComments.Value & _
           vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           Me.NewComment.Value & " ~ " & _
           VBA.DateTime.Date & " ~ " & VBA.DateTime.Time
  End If
  Me.NewComment.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works.  And thank you for explaining it too, it helps me learn.